# Regex: Select everything on a line before the round parentheses from a html tag

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, regex

I have this 3 html tags, I want to select everything on a line before the round parentheses:

```
<li><a href="page-1.html" title="Page 1">Page 1 (22)</a></li>
<li><a href="page-2.html" title="Page 2">Page 2 (18)</a></li>
<li><a href="page-3.html" title="Page 3">Page 3 (23)</a></li>
```

so, the output should be:

```
(22)</a></li>
(18)</a></li>
(23)</a></li>
```

my regex solution is:

FIND: `(?s)(<li><a href=.*?)(\()`

the problem is that my regex also selects the opening parenthese.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such job, [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) is your friend:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `<li><a href=.*?(?=\()`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **CHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<li><a href=        # literally
.*?                 # 0 or more any character
(?=\()              # positive lookahead, make sure we have an opening parenthesis after
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Nice the downvote! May I know why?

Answer (score -1):

SEARCH:  `(?s)(<li><a href=.*?)(\()`

REPLACE BY: `\2`